# Can't find the definition of a function in the implementation of bash

Tags: c, bash, github

I am trying to find out the definition of `maybe_make_export_env()` in the C implementation of bash in a github repository just forked from its original repository

But I can't find it, see https://github.com/timlee1/bash/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=+maybe_make_export_env&type=

Is it because I didn't use the search feature of github correctly, or because I didn't recognize the definition of the function?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use search feature of github, I just did `cscope -R` and search, Its there in `variables.c` at line no 4463

Comment: Is it a bug of github, or my failure to use github correctly?

Comment: @Stargateur how did you find it on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At most, search results can show two fragments from the same file, but
>   there may be more results within the file.

[Source](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search)

As you can see on your search:

```
variables.c
Showing the top two matches Last indexed 2 hours ago
```

I didn't find a way to show all matches, I think github just stop at the first two matches and quit. As @achal, you should next time use other tool that github search, like `grep` or `cscope`

So [here](https://github.com/timlee1/bash/blob/7de27456f6494f5f9c11ea1c19024d0024f31112/variables.c#L4463), the definition of `maybe_make_export_env()`.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if enterprise version of github also has such limit.

Comment: @Tim Seem that enterprise got the same limit, https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/searching-code/.